# STM32 USB host will not return from reset request

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, usb-host

Note: I have edited this question from its original content since I was able to find a deeper cause/symptom for the problem. I have re-written it to focus on that instead.

I am using a pretty basic configuration for the STM32F405 using the CubeMX configuration system.

Something (a clock, a setting.. something) is not configured correctly, and I can't tell how I could have possibly caused it. Though it could be a problem with the PCB I designed, that seems unlikely as the code runs and debugs and the SysTick interrupt is advancing the timing counter just fine.

I have tracked part of the problem down to this function

```
/* Reset after a PHY select and set Host mode */
USB_CoreReset(USBx)
```

Which times out, presumably because the core never comes out of reset (OTG_FS_GRSTCTL:CSRST == 1 always, after being set in that function. USB_CoreReset() tries to read CSRST==0 200,000 times, and if it fails it returns unsuccessfully).

> If you would like to generate this file and look at the output (or
>   adapt it to your board), you can take [this text](http://pastebin.com/ze7wF5K9) and paste it into
>   a file called "USB CSRST Problem.ioc". Note: It will probably require
>   some tweaking for your board since I have some pins assigned to
>   outputs for an LCD display.

I have tracked a discussion down that [describes similar symptoms](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.libopencm3/120), but I can confirm that my code **does** set OTG_HS_GUSBCFG:PHYSEL properly (confirmed setting bit 6 before the reset is performed), and generally adheres to the recommended startup procedure as outlined in that thread.

Clocks configuration:
[image: Clock configuration page of STM32CubeMX]

Comment: Check if have you have been using the latest stm32cube hal libraries , they constantly update them because they contain bugs mainly in USB , CAN and ethernet . and if you are using compiler like KEIL MDK then install the latest library package . The current state of software development for stm32 is a mess IMO.

Comment: I did this. Unfortunately they haven't fixed the VBUS activate bug, so I had to fix that again. (ie in the library: //this function turns on VBUS, next line: calls function with parameter that turns off VBUS). And semihosting quit working again. And my problem didn't budge. Legit tip though.

Comment: Got semihosting back. Forgot that you have to \n every printf, or you have to setbuf(stdout, NULL); for it to actually flush the buffer promptly.

Comment: Are u debugging using simulator or real time?

Comment: Debugging on-hardware.

Comment: are the registers declared volatile? are any optimizations done to ur code?Isnt GINTMSK an interrupt mask?So if u have masked all interrupts,how will the interrupt trigger?If you want to check if an interrupt has occurred or not shouldnt you be reading an interrupt status register and not the mask register??im talking generally,not particular to ur uC

Comment: i will try to replicate the problem , please specify the STM32 device you are using (STM32F407 ?) , type of development board if you are using one , and compiler (keil ....etc) , and capture a screen shot of the cubemx  configuration window , i would like to know if you are using RTOS or standalone

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD My concern is that I am trying to unmask the interrupt mask register, and it does not reflect the value I assigned to it. I'm not confusing it for the interrupt flag register.

Comment: STM32F405, and it is a custom board. Currently it is in the standalone configuration.

Comment: Oh, and it is GCC with optimizations turned off (makes stepping through code easier)

Comment: this is very weird since masking is not working , neither is assigning a value directly to the register ! so is there any function before/after this that is resetting or locking the value of this register ! or does this represent a compiler issue which is not likely to happen , try a another compiler if you are desperate like free version of KEIL or IAR !

Comment: could the address of the register be wrong in the .h file? try writing to memory location of USBx->GINTMSK instead of using its name.

Comment: My only working theory at the moment is that something isn't configured correctly (ie it's not enabled) and that the USB peripheral core is preventing interrupts from being unmasked because of this. The other registers in the peripheral ARE writeable and readable, including the USB global interrupt. I will check to make sure the absolute address of GINTMSK is correct, although I suspect that is ok.

Comment: USB_FS needs PLL48CK properly configured to output 48MHz (look at clock tree on the reference manual) before enabling clock input of peripheral. Is it OK?

Comment: another thing : USB with STM32cubemx should be a piece of cake, thats the whole point of using such software ! please listen and start looking into example codes and try them on your board , if they work start comparing the code and see the missing or spot the diffirence .

Comment: how are you so sure that your hardware is ok and the whole problem is in software ? when you face such problems , you have to start all over from capacitors and resistors to oscillators to see if you missed anything in schematic or in soldering the PCB .

Comment: @luchador I have added the clocks configuration page from the Cube configurator.

Comment: @ElectronS This is the second rev of this PCB. The first had no issues --all peripherals worked fine as far as I could tell...this is just to add USB. While there is still a chance that the hardware could be wrong, that seems to be less likely. I could totally see where you're coming from if there were any dedicated PLL supplies like on an FPGA, but I have the whole core running off my PLL now. (see clock diagram)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, here is the resolution.

@ElectronS was correct, sometimes you have to assume you don't know anything for sure. For example, I knew for sure that my 24MHz external oscillator was working fine because the whole core was running from it, according to the code generation configurator.

Well, apparently the STM32 will not allow you to select the external oscillator if it is not running. Or something. I don't have a good explanation.

Here is the core of the core of the problem: the Abracon ASDMB datasheet.

When it says

[image: Pin 1 - Standby]

What it means is

[image: Not Standby]

Which might more accurately be written as \$\overline{Standby}\$...

tl;dr the oscillator Enable pin was pulled low.

Thanks for all the feedback and pushing me to challenge my established thinking that had me stuck.

Comment: good work as they say the devil is in the details , finally we can sleep now:)

Answer (score 7):

Since you didnot upload the whole cubemx and generated code for the project i cannot fully try to replicate and find the problem.

But i will try to point you into few things that might/mightnot help :

1- make sure that  global non maskable interrupts are enabled , inaddition to USB OTG gloabl interrupt. in the configuration window , NVIC tab in cubemx project.

2- make sure you are using the correct mode , (using RTOS or standalone project , becuase the code generator may change things in RTOS mode or using DMA because DMA usually consider the interrupt as a request event). your problem might be somewhere else which is preventing write to this register, something like the lock sequence used for mapping I/O and peripherals.

3- There is 2 things called GINTMSK , a bit in OTG_FS_GAHBCFG register

[image: GINTMSK]

and a a register called : OTG_FS_GINTMSK

[image: GINTMSK 2]

4- The correct programming sequence is used :
[image: sequence]

5- Search in smt32cube directory / projects / stm32xx discovery / applications/ 
in this folder you will find multiple projects on USB applications depending on your deivce , use these codes as starter and compare the initalization to your code.

Comment: I am familiar with this page of the manual, but the Cube code does not follow it, really at all.

Comment: For example, I added debug messages to (one of the two) functions that turns on the USB VBUS line, and it is called three different times.

Comment: Credit for making an attempt. Still a lot of work left to do to figure this out unfortunately. Tomorrow I start mapping every bit of every register being touched in the USB subsystem... :(

Comment: You were right in the comments to my question. The external clock was not oscillating. That creates a new mystery of how the code was executing when it should have been running from that clock (and I don't have clock protection turned on). I just needed someone to force me to question everything. That's worth 1,000,000 internet points as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: i have been their before , facing problem that could drive one crazy and very difficult to trace , (sometimes wrong footprint , sometimes datasheet mistakes , eratta , you name it)  ,  The thing is that maybe the debugger (st-link) was providing the clock ??

Answer (score 3):

I think what was happing is that , even though your oscillator is not providing clock , the micocontroller was running at power on from its internal RC oscillator . Heres a qoute from [Things to remember when coding stm32](http://www.emcu.it/STM32/STM32VLDiscovery_Test/Things%20to%20remember%20when%20developing%20a%20program%20for%20STM32%20using%20STM32-Library.html)

"Don't forget to enable the external or internal oscillator that you need to use for SYSCLK.
At power-on for default is enabled the internal RC oscillator HSI."

There should be also a startup timer that forces the micro into reset until the oscillator is stable and from the PLL to lock ( i used that in dspic processors ) , if clock is not stable switchover from internal RC to external doesnot happen and program gets stuck.